# Finding nearest missing number in list Python

Tags: python, list, range

I have a list in Python, how can I find the smallest empty number in this list?

Example:

[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]

The numbers 3 and 8 are missing in this ordered list. How do I find the smallest number 3?

```
class Find():

    def finding(self):
        a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
        
        b = sorted(a)
        print(b)
        cont = 1

        for index in range(len(b)):
            cont = index+1
            cont = len(b)+1
        print("empty value: " + str(cont))

Find = Find()   
Find.finding()
```

Since I will add different codes later, the self finding(self) argument is required.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far, as per: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Is the list always supposed to start with `1`? What if no number is missing?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach: iterate over pairs of adjacent numbers, and return the first one where the later number is greater by more than 1.

```
>>> def find_missing(arr):
...     return next(a + 1 for a, b in zip(arr, arr[1:]) if b > a + 1)
...
>>> find_missing([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9])
3
```

If you need to call this from `Find.finding()` you could do:

```
def find_missing(arr):
    return next(a + 1 for a, b in zip(arr, arr[1:]) if b > a + 1)

class Find():

    def finding(self):
        a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
        print(f"empty value: {find_missing(sorted(a))}")

Find = Find()   
Find.finding()
```

The loop that you wrote doesn't accomplish anything because it doesn't look at the values of the list, and it overwrites the `cont` variable with `len(b) + 1`.  You might have more luck with something like:

```
    for index in range(len(b)):
        cont = index + 1
        if b[index] + 1 != b[cont]:
            print(f"empty value: {b[index] + 1}")
            break
```

Comment: It's unclear whether the series is always assumed to start at 1.  If it were a cheesy fix would be to iterate over `zip([0] + arr, arr)` rather than `zip(arr, arr[1:])`.

Comment: Or `next(b for a, b in zip(arr, count(1)) if a != b)`

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't get this to work.
Can you give an example of my code please?
https://prnt.sc/1ux6nfu
Thank you.

Comment: If you include your code in a question, somebody will probably post an answer explaining what's wrong with it.  Doing it in a comment is difficult.  (Remember to post the actual code, not a screenshot of it!  Use your cursor to select the text so you can copy + paste.)

Comment: @Samwise I did. Can you please check this?

Comment: @Samwise Thanks it worked! But there is a problem.
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 

I get an error if the list is like this. How can I get it to assign (10) the next number?

Comment: `try: return next(...)` `except StopIteration: return arr[-1] + 1`

Comment: @Samwise Can you share a expamle?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution: loop through the lst (sorted) and a range of numbers with the same length of the lst. If the item from the lst is ever greater than the range item, return that range item to get the "empty" value.

Code:

```js
def findSmallestEmpty(lst):
  lst.sort()
  relevantRange = range(1, len(lst))
  for lstElement, rangeElement in zip(lst, relevantRange):
    if lstElement > rangeElement:
      return rangeElement

lst = [1, 2, 4, 5]

element = findSmallestEmpty(lst)
```

This assumes that all the numbers are positive and that the lowest possible number is 1.

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: it worked for me on the given example (the example in the code, where 3 would be the first smallest missing value). What input list is it failing on?